# mysql query based on length of string in a column

Tags: mysql

I am trying to query a table in mysql based on the length of a string in a specific column. I know mysql has a function called LENGTH(), but that returns the length of the string. I want to be able to pull data based on the result of the LENGTH() function.

Example:

```
SELECT * table WHERE LENGTH(word) = 6
```

of course that does not work. I read through http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function%5Flength but could not find anything to help me.

yes I could make something in PhP to accomplish this, but I would like to do it at the query level.

Any help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT *
    FROM table
    WHERE LENGTH(RTRIM(word)) = 6
```

Comment: I would recommend using the `CHAR_LENGTH()` function instead of `LENGTH()`, that way you're counting characters instead of bytes.

Comment: worked perfect, ultimatly I am making a query statement that will pull results based on "String Length", "Possible Characters", and not "Including Characters" in words. I have the first 2 so far

Answer (score 0):

I believe you wanted to use query `SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE LENGTH(word) = 6;` (assuming that the `word` is name of column in `tableName`).

This is very unfortunate solution on large tables, you should create new column and use `UPDATE tableName SET wordLength = LENGTH( word)`.